# Persist Entitys in Database instead of appsettings.json

Tags: c#, policy-server

I have an Project where I user IdentityServer4 and PolicyServer.Local.
IdentityServer4 already has an implementation for storing the necessary data in a database, but PolicyServer doesnt.

So i tried to implement it myself, with success, but it feels not good in the sense that i think iam replacing to much of the PolicyServers Code.

Like for example I have replaced all of the PolicyServers Entity classes (Policy, Permission, Roles) and added my own ones so I can resolve the List Properties, all that because Entity Framework cant map List basically.

I also added my own PolicyServerRuntimeClient, because I needed to adjust the Evaluate-Methods to the new Entity-classes.

First of my Startup.cs:

```
        services.AddDbContext<AuthorizeDbContext>(builder => 
            builder.UseSqlite(csAuthorizeContext, sqlOptions =>
                sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));

        services.AddScoped<IAuthorizeService, AuthorizeService>()
            .AddTransient<IPolicyServerRuntimeClient, CustomPolicyServerRuntimeClient>()
            .AddScoped(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<Policy>>().Value);
        new PolicyServerBuilder(services).AddAuthorizationPermissionPolicies();
```

(AuthorizeService is for getting the values from the Database)

For Example this is my Permission-, Roles- and to resolve the m-n relationship a PermissionRoles-classes.

```
public class Permission
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Policy")]
    public string PolicyId { get; set; }

    public IList<PermissionRole> PermissionRoles { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionRole
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PermissionId { get; set; }

    public Permission Permission { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<PermissionRole> PermissionRoles { get; set; }
}
```

and this would be my Evalute-Methods in the CustomPolicyServerRuntimeClient:

```
    public async Task<PolicyResult> EvaluateAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

        var sub = user.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sub))
            return null;

        var roles =  _auth.Roles
            .ToList()
            .Where(x => EvaluateRole(x, user))
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToArray();

        var permissions = _auth.Permissions
            .ToList()
            .Where(x => EvaluatePermission(x, roles))
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToArray();

        var result = new PolicyResult()
        {
            Roles = roles.Distinct(),
            Permissions = permissions.Distinct()
        };

        return await Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    internal bool EvaluateRole(Role role, ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

        var subClaim = user.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;

        var subjectsOfDbRole = _auth.UserDetails
            .ToList()
            .Where(x => x.RoleId.Equals(role.Id))
            .Select(x => x.Subject)
            .ToList();

        return subjectsOfDbRole.Contains(subClaim);
    }

    public bool EvaluatePermission(Permission permission, IEnumerable<string> roles)
    {
        if (roles == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(roles));

        var permissionRoles = _auth.PermissionRoles
            .ToList()
            .Where(y => y.PermissionId.Equals(permission.Id))
            .ToList();

        if (permissionRoles.Any(x => roles.Contains(x.Role.Name)))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

these are the main changes I did to get it working.

I dont want to do to much work in the Backend before I figure out how to do this correctly.

Expected result was that I probably just needed to replace

```
        services.Configure<Policy>(configuration);
```

but in the end I did replace way more than expected.

Comment: `appsettings.json` has no special meaning. It's just a json file that's read by .NET Core's configuration subsystem. That subsystem can read *any* source that returns settings in a `section::subsection::subsubsection::key` form, whether it's a database, command line, environment variables. Instead of trying to replace all classes, look for the code that loads settings from `appsettings.json`. If you add your *own* configuration source that provides the same keys/values, you can point it to any source you want

Comment: Check the [Configuration in ASP.NET Core / Custom provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-configuration-provider). It shows how you can create your own provider that reads values from a database instead of a file. This article explains how the entire Configuration system works, how the source *doesn't* matter as long as you end up with a dictionary of flat keys and values, and how later providers override those registered earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I didnt get it to work. 
The error message was: "An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: The property 'Permission.Roles' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List<string>' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."

Comment: And in my Program.cs I have:
"ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
       config.AddEFConfiguration(options => options.UseSqlite("DataSource=.\\AuthorizeContext.sqlite3"));
})

Comment: did you read the article? The configuration data you return must be a key/value pair. The key should contain the full path to the value. Just as the documentation example stores `array:entries:0` in a dictionary your database configuration provider should return pairs whose keys are `Policy:roles:0:name` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have to change anything in PolicyServer, just add a new configuration provider that returns the settings you want. PolicyServer reads its configuration from .NET Core's configuration infrastructure. It's not tied to `appsettings.json`.

.NET Core [can read configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) from any source through [providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#providers). Those providers don't do anything complicated, they "just" read whatever their actual source is and produce key/value string pairs in the form:

```
"array:entries:0"= "value0"
"array:entries:1"= "value1"
"array:entries:2"= "value2"
"array:entries:4"= "value4"
"array:entries:5"= "value5"
```

`appsettings.json` has no special meaning, it's just a JSON file from which .NET Core's [JSON configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#json-configuration-provider) reads key/value settings. The file can be named anything at all. The same data could be loaded from a dictionary, a database, a remote configuration service etc.

This dictionary for example :

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> arrayDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"array:entries:0", "value0"},
        {"array:entries:1", "value1"},
        {"array:entries:2", "value2"},
        {"array:entries:4", "value4"},
        {"array:entries:5", "value5"}
    };
```

Provides the *same* configuration data as this JSON file :

```
{
    "array" : {
        "entries" : [
            "value1",
            "value2",
            "value3",
            "value4",
            "value5"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Using a dictionary**

You could load PolicyServer's settings from a dictionary using the [Memory configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#memory-configuration-provider). In your configuration section,  :

```
public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _dict = 
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Policy:roles:0:name", "doctor"},
        {"Policy:roles:0:subjects:0", "1"},
        {"Policy:roles:0:subjects:1", "2"},
        {"Policy:roles:1:name", "patient"},
        {"Policy:roles:1:identityRoles:0", "customer"},
    };

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddInMemoryCollection(_dict);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

When you call `AddPolicyServerClient(Configuration.GetSection("Policy"))` in your service registration code, the settings will come from that dictionary.

**Using a raw table**

You could create your own configuration provider as shown in [Custom Configuration Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-configuration-provider) that retrieved settings from an `ID/Value` table. You'd have to store the full key in the `ID` field, which can be a bit annoying, eg :

```
CREATE TABLE MyPolicySettings (ID varchar(200) PRIMARY KEY,value varchar(200))
INSERT INTO TABLE MyPolicySettings (ID,Value)
VALUES
("Policy:roles:0:name",            "doctor"},
("Policy:roles:0:subjects:0",      "1"),
("Policy:roles:0:subjects:1",      "2"),
("Policy:roles:1:name",            "patient"),
("Policy:roles:1:identityRoles:0", "customer");
```

**Using EF**

Another option is to store your settings in proper tables eg, `Roles`, `Subjects`, `IdentityRoles` and use an ORM to load the entire structure. Once you have it, you'll have to reproduce the key structure, eg by iterating over the objects in an iterator :

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> FlattenRoles(IEnumerable<MyRole> roles)
{
    int iRole=0;
    foreach(var role in roles)
    {           
        var rolePart=$"Policy:roles:{i}";
        var namePair=new KeyValuePair($"{rolePart}:name",role.Name);
        yield return namePair;
        int iSubject=0;
        foreach(var subjectPair in FlattenSubjects(role.Subject))
        {
            yield return subjectPair
        }
        //Same for identity roles etc
        iRole++;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> FlattenSubjects(IEnumerable<MySubject> subjects,string rolePart)
{
    var pairs=subjects.Select((subject,idx)=>
              new KeyValuePair($"{rolePart}:subjects:{idx}",subject.Value);
    return pairs;
}
```

Your custom configuration provider could use this to load strongly-typed classes from the database, flatten them and convert them to a dictionary, eg :

```
public class MyPolicyConfigurationProvider: ConfigurationProvider
{
    public MyPolicyConfigurationProvider(Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction)
    {
        OptionsAction = optionsAction;
    }

    Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> OptionsAction { get; }

    // Load config data from EF DB.
    public override void Load()
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyPoliciesContext>();

        OptionsAction(builder);

        using (var dbContext = new MyPoliciesContext(builder.Options))
        {
            var keys=FlattenRoles(dbContext.Roles);
            Data=new Dictionary<string,string>(keys);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this explains creating a custom Configuration really well and it works like a charm with adding the Roles in the Dictionary and InMemoryCollection. I will try to add the values into a Table in my Database with the instructions you gave. Thanks!